# chrome unpacked extension error: Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 7, column: 16, Syntax error

Tags: json

here's the code:

```
{
"name": "Conjuguemos",
"description": "Learn Spanish, French, Italian, Portuguese, Latin, and German",
"version": "1.0.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"icons": {
"128″: "icon_128.png"
},
"app": {
"urls": [
"https://conjuguemos.com/"
],
"launch": {
"web_url": “https://conjuguemos.com/"
}
}
}
```

apparently there is a syntax error somewhere in line 7, can somebody show me whats wrong? i'm so confused. :/

Answer (score 1):

Your closing quote of 128 is a different quote than the opening one. (`"` does not equal `″`)

Comment: Also `2` should be quoted.